# Failed to resolve firebase-ui-auth

Tags: java, android, firebase, gradle, firebaseui

When I use implementation `'com.firebase.firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'` it pops up an ***error*** 
I even tried to change it to **3.3.1** then it shows a failure that it could no find the package

I have change it to **16.0.1** too then too an error is my app compact version is **v7-28.0.0**

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'  
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui.firebase-ui-auth:3.3.0'
```

the above two packages are properly implemented when I use `firebase-ui-auth` it fails to load my android version is **3.1.3**

Error messsage: Failed to resolve: `com.firebaseui.firebase-ui-auth:3.1.3:`

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui.firebase-ui-auth:3.3.0'
```

into this:

```
 implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.0'
```

You have a typo, it should be `:` instead of `.`

`com.firebaseui` is the group id

`firebase-ui-auth` is the artifact id

`3.3.0` is the version

---

It is better to use the latest `FirebaseUI` version which is `4.3.0`:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.2'
```

Check the docs for more info:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#installation